# Selecting all rows that have a value in the top N rows

Tags: sql, sqlite

Consider this simple table of event counts:

| event_name | count |
| --- | --- |
| viewLoaded | 20 |
| viewUnloaded | 17 |
| buttonTapped | 12 |
| viewScrolled | 12 |
| networkSuccess | 9 |
| linkTapped | 9 |
| networkFailure | 2 |
| leapSecond | 0 |

I would like to select the top N events by count, but with the additional requirement that if the result set includes *any* event with a particular count, then it should include *all* of the events with that count. In other words, I don’t want to break up any of the “groups” of rows that have the same count. Instead, I will potentially get more rows than I asked for.

For example, if I wanted the “top five” events in the table above, the query would actually return six rows so that both events with count 9 were included. The query for the top four would return four rows, and the query for the top three would also return four rows.

How can I accomplish this in SQLite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `RANK` window function for this task. It's ranking value will be equal for the identical values, but will consider the amount of past rows when needs to assign the next ranking.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY count_ DESC) AS rn
    FROM events
)
SELECT event_name, count_ FROM cte WHERE rn <= 5
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dTxtAZmRuovQcQWy7w9pJT/1).

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use a common table expression to identify the counts corresponding to the “top five” events:

```
with top_five as (
    select count from events order by count desc limit 5
)
select * from events where count in top_five order by count desc;
```